# $.fn.<new_function> 'is not a function' jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-plugins, prototype

**EDIT: code link with better formatting:**
**EDIT: code updated with improvements from JSHint**

http://pastebin.com/hkDQfZy1

I am trying to use $.fn to create a new function on jQuery objects by using it like:

```
$.fn.animateAuto = function(x,y) { }
```

And calling it by:

```
var card = $(id);
.....
var expanderButton = card.find(".dock-bottom");
.....
expanderButton.animateAuto('height', 500);
```

and I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: expanderButton.animateAuto is not a function
```

What am I doing incorrectly?  The $.cssHooks extension works just fine along with $.fx.

Here is the code:

```
var CSS_VIS = 'visibility'
var CSS_VIS_VIS = 'visible';
var CSS_VIS_HID = 'hidden';
var CSS_TEXTBOX_CONTAINER = ".text-box-container";

$.cssHooks['rotate'] = {
get: function (elem, computed, extra) {
    var property = getTransformProperty(elem);
    if (property) {
        return elem.style[property].replace(/.*rotate\((.*)deg\).*/, '$1');
    } else {
        return '';
    }
},
set: function (elem, value) {
    var property = getTransformProperty(elem);
    if (property) {
        value = parseInt(value);
        $(elem).data('rotatation', value);
        if (value == 0) {
            elem.style[property] = '';
        } else {
            elem.style[property] = 'rotate(' + value % 360 + 'deg)';
        }
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
};
$.fn.animateAuto = function (prop, speed) {
return this.each(function (i, el) {
    el = jQuery(el);
    var element = el.clone().css({ 'height': 'auto' }).appendTo("body");
    var height = element.css("height");
    var width = element.css("width");
    element.remove();

    if (prop === "height") {
        el.animate({ 'height': height }, speed);
    } else if (prop = "width") {
        el.animate({ 'width': width }, speed);
    } else if (prop = "both") {
        el.animate({ 'height': height, 'width:': width }, speed);
    }
});
}
$.fx.step['rotate'] = function (fx) {
$.cssHooks['rotate'].set(fx.elem, fx.now);
};
function getTransformProperty(element) {
var properties = [
    'transform',
    'WebkitTransform',
    'MozTransform',
    'msTransform',
    'OTransform'];
var p;
while (p = properties.shift()) {
    if (element.style[p] !== undefined) {
        return p;
    }
}
return false;
}
function isExpanded(card) {
return card.find(CSS_TEXTBOX_CONTAINER).css(CSS_VIS) == CSS_VIS_VIS;
}

function expandCard(id) {
var card = $(id);
var isCardExpanded = isExpanded(card);
var expanderButton = card.find(".dock-bottom");
card.animate({
    height: isCardExpanded ? '80px' : '270px'
}, 500);

var startValue = isCardExpanded ? 1 : 0;
var endValue = isCardExpanded ? 0 : 1;
var visibilityValue = isCardExpanded ? CSS_VIS_HID : CSS_VIS_VIS;
var textBoxes = card.find(CSS_TEXTBOX_CONTAINER);
textBoxes.fadeTo(0, startValue);
textBoxes.css(CSS_VIS, visibilityValue).fadeTo(500, endValue);

var topValue = isCardExpanded ? 'auto' : '200px';
if (isCardExpanded) {
    expanderButton.animateAuto('height', 500);
} else {
    expanderButton.animate({
        top: '200px'
    }, 500);
}

expanderButton.find("span").text(isCardExpanded ? "More Info" : "Less Info");

var buttonthing = expanderButton.find("button");
expanderButton.find("button").animate({ rotate: isCardExpanded ? 0 : -180 });
};
```

Comment: Have you defined the function in scope of where your calling it? Is it included in the page? Have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: The function is defined in the same file as the client code; its all in my 'wafer-creation-card.js' file.  The 'Uncaught TypeError' posted above is the error I get the chrome developer tools.

Comment: FYI, separate problem: `if (prop = "width")` should be `if (prop == "width")` or `if (prop === "width")`, same for the following comparison too.

Comment: The one thing that jsHint points out is that you should either have a blank line or a semi-colon at the end of the `$.fn.animateAuto` function definition.  Not sure if that causes a problem or not, but that kind of issue can occasionally cause a problem.  When I'm getting a weird error, I immediately go put the code into jsHint and fix issues it points out.  At worst, it cleans up your code.  Many times, it fixes something.

Comment: Hard to read your code with messed up indentation.

Comment: I tried $(expanderButton).animateAuto - doesn't solve the problem.  Also tried a space and/or comma after closing brace of the $.fn.animateAuto function and that also doesn't work....

Comment: jfriend00 : http://pastebin.com/adbmWjF8

Comment: It should have been a semi-colon after closing brace of `$.fn.animateAuto` function definition.  Did you past your code into http://jshint.com and fix most of the things it shows you?  Always a good place to start.

Comment: Updated the code with some of the hints recommended by JSHint... the issue still remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that jQuery was loaded multiple times.  I am using ASP.NET MVC5 and was loading jQuery in the PartialView (re-usable UI control) and the main page which was causing my extension to be overriden.

I would post code but it would be too verbose and has nothing to do with jQuery or JavaScript.  To solve though, all I did was remove the jQuery script import from the PartialView since jQuery is imported on every page by the master page.

Thanks everyone for helping out though, you all proved to me that this was not a simple problem that I was overthinking and that more research was necessary.